# How to find and replace (or add) specific word in a specific category?

Tags: customization

I have a site and all posts have a download link. Download link is like this : `http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip`

I want to add different word before filename for each category. Forexample :

For A category, I want to add ACategory before filename. New link will be like this : `http://sitename.com/FileID/ACategory-filename.zip`

For B category, I want to add BCategory before filename. New link will be like this : `http://sitename.com/FileID/BCategory-filename.zip`

How can I do this? Is there any plugin or is there any way to do this in phpmyadmin?

EDIT :

I found this code to find and replace in only a category which I selected :

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships r JOIN wp_posts p 
ON r.object_id = p.id JOIN wp_terms t
ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x
ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
SET p.post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Item to replace here', 'Replacement text here')
WHERE t.name = 'CATEGORY '
AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
```

Now I couldn't find any way to change `http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip` **to** `http://sitename.com/FileID/ACategory-filename.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution after a long time of trying-

```
UPDATE wp_posts p 
       JOIN wp_term_relationships r 
         ON r.object_id = p.id 
       JOIN wp_terms t 
         ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id 
       JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x 
         ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id 
SET    p.post_content = CASE
    WHEN t.name = 'ACategory' THEN REPLACE(post_content, 'http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip', 
                               'http://sitename.com/FileID/ACategory-filename.zip')
    WHEN t.name = 'BCategory' THEN REPLACE(post_content, 'http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip', 
                               'http://sitename.com/FileID/BCategory-filename.zip')
    ELSE post_content
    END
WHERE x.taxonomy = 'category'
```

Look closely, I made some changes to your code. And give special attention to the `CASE` command which I included to the code. For each category name add an extra `WHEN t.name = 'Your-Category-Name' THEN REPLACE(post_content, 'http://sitename.com/FileID/filename.zip', 'http://sitename.com/FileID/new-filename.zip')`.

Hope that helps.

> ***I tested it and it worked perfectly in my system.***

Comment: Thanks you for answer. But there are a lot of links and all links FileID section is different. So, I think we have to use regex

Comment: You said for each category you need to change the file addresses, so in that `CASE` command you can set the file URL for each category. And I've not understood how you want to regex with this ? @Yearmaz

Comment: Think like that : There is 5 categories and each category has 150 posts. All posts have a download link like sitename.com/u3hu2h3u1/file1.zip , sitename.com/1fgy15345/file2.zip , sitename.com/1f73ydh3342/file3.zip ...etc. So all links FileID section is different and I want to add category name before filename. Result will be like : sitename.com/u3hu2h3u1/CategoryA-file1.zip